# javascript setTimeout call error

Tags: javascript, scope, call, settimeout, invoke

I want to invoke the [`window.setTimeot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function with my custom scope so I use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) method, but there is something wrong.

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log("keep going");
        window.setTimeout.call(this,this.bar,100);
    }
    this.bar();
}

new foo;
```

under Firefox this prints to the console only 1 line and then nothing, and under google chrome it throws a [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError).

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `call` does not help here: it calls `setTimeout` with your `this` object, but the callback function itself is still called from the global scope. What you really want to do is something like this:

```
function foo() {
    var self = this;
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log("keep going");
        window.setTimeout(function() { self.bar(); }, 100);
    }
    this.bar();
}
```

**Edit:** If you really want something similar to the `call` approach, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which binds the `this` value for a function:

```
window.setTimeout(this.bar.bind(this), 100);
```

However, this is part of the new ECMAScript 5 spec which is not yet supported by all browsers.

Comment: thanks, i know that this way works, i am trying to use the `call`.

Comment: @omnosis: You cannot use `call` for this purpose. What you're looking for is [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which is part of the new ECMAScript 5 spec. Using that, you can do something like this: `window.setTimeout(this.bar.bind(this), 100)`.

Comment: makes perfect sense. I made the same mistake, makes no sense to use `call` on `setTimeout` because you're not trying to change the `this` of `setTimeout`, but rather, the function you are passing as an argument. cheers