# Javascript binding using call with setInterval

Tags: javascript, binding, call, setinterval, object-literal

How can I use "call" with "setInterval" to get an object literal to invoke one of its own methods?

Here's an example.
This works, and I understand why it works.
The timer object calls its own tick method once each second

```
var timer =
{ 
  start: function()
  {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);

  },

  tick: function()
  {
    console.log("tick!");
  }
};

timer.start();
```

I tried to simplify this code by using "call".
This next example is the best that I came up with.
But it doesn't work: the tick method is called only once, and then I get a type error.

```
var timer =
{ 
  start: function()
  {
    setTimeout.call(this, this.tick(), 1000);
  },

  tick: function()
  {
    console.log("tick!");
  }
};

timer.start();
```

I think I don't really understand how call works.
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112330/javascript-settimeout-call-error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are `.calling` `.setInterval` not your callback function which the browser calls:

```
setInterval( this.tick.bind(this), 1000 );
```

Should work. See [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: With Safari 5.1.5 this gives me "TypeError: undefined is not a function". Firefox 8.0.1 gives me "uncaught exception: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object."

Comment: @user1282216 see the link. I assume developers don't use outdated software for development but apparently I was wrong :P. The firefox error is interesting, can you give me a jsfiddle on that?

Comment: @user1282216 nevermind I can reproduce that error in firefox 13, you are doing it wrong. Use the code `setInterval( this.tick.bind(this), 1000)` instead of `setInterval.call( this )` (that causes the error)

Comment: do u know how can I add, some argument to my method ( tick )??, thanks im trying this: setInterval( this.tick("arg_1").bind(this), 1000 );

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up with:

```
  var timer = {
    time: 0,
    start: function() {
      var timerTick = this.tick.bind(this);
      window.setInterval(function() {
        timerTick();
      }, 1000);
    },
    tick: function() {
      this.time += 1;
      console.log(this.time);
    }
  };

  timer.start();
```