# getting length of array within separate method in class JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I get an error when I try to get the length of the sprites array in the for loop of my move function but not in the redraw function. It appears to properly draw the square using redraw but doesn't like it when I use the move function. I'm kinda new to classes in JS(and posting on Stack Overflow) so I was hoping some of you could help me with this

```
class Canvas {
  init() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.sprites = []; //array hold objects with each sprites x, y, and r
    this.active = false;
  }
  
  ball(r, clickMult, speed) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
    this.sprites.push({x: 0, y: 0, r: r, xVel: speed, yVel: speed});
    this.#redraw();
    if (!this.active) {
      setInterval(this.#move, 200);
      this.active = true;
    }
  }

  #redraw() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sprites.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.fillRect(this.sprites[i].x, this.sprites[i].y, this.sprites[i].r, this.sprites[i].r);
      this.ctx.fill();
      this.ctx.closePath();
    }
  }

  #move() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sprites.length; i++) {
      this.sprites[i].x += this.sprites[i].xVel;
      this.sprites[i].y += this.sprites[i].yVel;
    }
    
    this.#checkCollision();
    this.#redraw();
  }

  #checkCollision() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sprites.length; i++) {
      if (this.sprites[i].x < 0) {
        this.sprites[i].x = 0;
        this.sprites[i].xVel *= -1;
      } else if (this.sprites[i].x + this.sprites[i].r > this.canvas.width) {
        this.sprites[i].x = this.canvas.width - this.sprites[i].r;
        this.sprites[i].xVel *= -1;
      }
  
      if (this.sprites[i].y < 0) {
        this.sprites[i].y = 0;
        this.sprites[i].yVel *= -1;
      } else if (this.sprites[i].y + this.sprites[i].r > this.canvas.width) {
        this.sprites[i].y = this.canvas.width - this.sprites[i].r;
        this.sprites[i].yVel *= -1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result that continues popping up is that length is undefined but it does this in the move function but not the redraw function despite them appearing to be the same

Comment: *"length is undefined"* - Is that the exact error message?  Can you include code which actually uses this class to present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David The exact error message is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: Then `length` is not `undefined` as you indicate in the question, `this.sprites` is.  Can you include code which actually uses this class to present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Most likely you're not calling the method properly, so `this` is the global `window` object rather than a `Canvas` instance, and there's no `sprites` property.

Comment: @David Someone needs to tell the JavaScript implementors to reword that error message. Hardly a day goes by without someone posting a question where they misunderstand it.

Comment: @David The only times I call the class functions are once at the start of the html `<body>
  <h1 id = "clickCounter">Clicks: 0</h1>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>
  <button id = "b1" class = "button"></button>
  <canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    app.init();
    draw.init();
  </script>
</body>` as well as  `  if (clicks >= 100 && !upgrade[3]) {
    upgrade[3] = true;
    draw.ball(5, 1, 20);
    draw.ball(5, 1, 20);
  }`  which is in a function that gets checked on a button click

Comment: @VioletFrench: Is the `move` method only ever called here? `setInterval(this.#move, 200)`  I suspect the problem is indeed that `this` isn't what you expect when `move` is invoked.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11241607/328193) looks like a useful place to start, and may even solve the issue entirely.  There's also considerably more information about the `this` keyword [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/328193).

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was because of the callback function of the set interval method. I'm not sure why but instead of calling this.#move every 200 ms I changed it to call an unnamed function () => {} which would then call this.#move()

Comment: Many answers in the comments again ...

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you post an example of how you are using this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was found and resolved, all that was required was changing the callback function of the setInterval method

instead of
setInterval(this.#move, 200)
I changed it to
setInterval(() => {this.#move();}, 200);
Which seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: You can simplify it to `this.#move.bind(this)`